# Show that $A$ defined by a continuous function is open

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Consider a continuous function defined all of $R^n$ i.e., $h:R^n \to R$. Also obtain the infimum of $h$
$$ a: = \inf_{x\in R^n} h(x) $$

Define the set $A := \{ x \in R^n : h(x) > a \}$. Is $A$ open?

I was trying to show that it is open. If $A$ is all of $R^n$ then it is open. We will consider the case when $A \subset R^n$. If $A$ is a strict subset of $R^n$ then its complement exists. Denote it by $A^c$. Also, since $h(x)$ is defined over all $R^n$ and $a$ is the infimum, we can obtain $A^c$ explicitly as
$$ A^c = \{ x \in R^n : h(x) = a \}$$

It remains to show that $A^c$ is closed. Suppose that $A^c$ is not closed. Then there is a sequence of points in $A^c$: $x_1, x_2, \dots$ such that $\lim_{n\to \infty} x_n  \notin A^c$. This is a contradiction since $h$ is continuous and 
$ h(x_n) = a$ for every $n$, and its limit is $a$.

Did I get this right? Is there a better proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof works. However, there is an easier way. Note that $B = \{y\in \Bbb R\mid y>a\}$ is open in $\Bbb R$, and $A = f^{-1}(B)$. Since $f$ is continuous, that means that $A$ is open. (This works even if $a = -\infty$, in which case $B = \Bbb R$ and $A = \Bbb R^n$.)

Comment: Great! Thank you. This seems to work even for $a \geq \inf_{x\in R^n} h(x)$.

Comment: @Shishir It does indeed.

Comment: On a second thought, consider $h(x) =sin (x)$ so $a = -1$, but, with the set $B$ defined as above, $h^{-1}$ is not defined for $x>1$. So I will need to pick $B$ appropriately, something like $B = \{ y\in R | b > y > a \}$, where $b = \sup h(x)$.

Comment: @Shishir No, you don't have to do that. $h^{-1}$ as a function of _points_ isn't defined, but as a function on _subsets_ it's defined regardless of the image of $h$. For instance, with the open interval $(3, 4)$, we have that $h^{-1}((3, 4)) = \varnothing$ is open, so there is no problem.

Comment: OIC. That is correct! Thanks. That is by definition of continuity of $h$.